# hide the input tag with the associated attributes

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to hide the input type tags with the attribute **keep-current-customization="false"**. my code is :

```
var example = jQuery.noConflict();
example(function () {
    example.attr("input[keep-current-customization='false']").hide();
});
```

but its not working.

Below is how the source looks on the page:

```
  <h3>Current Carrier Questionnaire<strong style="color: Red;"></strong></h3>

  <div class="desc">
      To keep your current home phone number,  please complete the below.</div>
  <br />

  <div class="textgrid">
       <div class="feildset1">
            Account holders name on your current phone bill?: </br>
            <input name="rptCustomization$ctl07$rptItems$ctl00$ctrl" type="text" maxlength="100" id="rptCustomization_rptItems_7_ctrl_0" keep-current-customization="false" /></br>
           <br />
       </div>
   </div>

   <div class="textgrid">
        <div class="feildset1">
             Current phone company you have?: </br>
             <input name="rptCustomization$ctl07$rptItems$ctl01$ctrl" type="text" maxlength="100" id="rptCustomization_rptItems_7_ctrl_1" keep-current-customization="false" /></br>
             <br />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="textgrid">
         <div class="feildset1">
              What is the account # with your current provider?: </br>
              <input name="rptCustomization$ctl07$rptItems$ctl02$ctrl" type="text" maxlength="100" id="rptCustomization_rptItems_7_ctrl_2" keep-current-customization="false" /></br>
              <br />
         </div>
    </div>

    <div class="textgrid">
         <div class="feildset1">
              What is the PIN/access code for current provider?: </br>
              <input name="rptCustomization$ctl07$rptItems$ctl03$ctrl" type="text" maxlength="100" id="rptCustomization_rptItems_7_ctrl_3" keep-current-customization="false" /></br>
              <br />
         </div>
     </div>

     <div class="textgrid">
          <div class="feildset1">
               What are the two nearest cross streets?: </br>
               <input name="rptCustomization$ctl07$rptItems$ctl04$ctrl" type="text" maxlength="100" id="rptCustomization_rptItems_7_ctrl_4" keep-current-customization="false" /></br>
               <br />
           </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dont put `.attr` to example :

```
example("input[keep-current-customization='false']").hide();
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Pascalz/3z4WT/)

Comment: this also works but i need to remove the div with id textgrid which inside contains the input tag with attribute keep-current-customization=false What i need to do in this case?

Comment: do like this :    example(".textgrid").has("input[keep-current-customization='false']").hide();  http://jsfiddle.net/Pascalz/3z4WT/1/

Comment: Except with a hash symbol rather than a period as it is an ID rather than a class

Comment: @pwdst I see a class but maybe i need glasses

Comment: The OP got it wrong in their follow up specifications, it is indeed a class in the code sample. Using StackOverflow on a tablet with limited screen real estate so didn't spot their mistake - sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Pascalz.. that worked absolutely..! Had wasted almost all the day on it.. Many thanks brother!

Answer (score 3):

```
var example = jQuery.noConflict();
example(function () {
    example("input[keep-current-customization=false]").hide();
});
```

No attr() function needed for selecting elements in this case.

Comment: this works but i need to remove the div with id textgrid which indeed contains the attribute keep-current-customization=false

What i need to do in this case?

Comment: You may use has() selector for additional filtration, for example "div:has(input[keep-current-customization=false])" selects all divs with inputs. And then hide those divs.

Answer (score 3):

The attr() function sets or gets attribute values on given elements. To find elements with a certain attribute value, try this:

```
$("input[keep-current-customization='false']").hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input[keep-current-customization='false']").hide();
```